# How to solve the "/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output" error when compiling RELION software

Tags: compilation

I am trying to install the RELION software. Following the installation guide , I finished the initial steps without error, which include:

```
git clone https://github.com/3dem/relion.git
cd relion
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

but when compiling with make, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(direct2.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(hc2hc-direct.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.